# How to manage django missing migration files of 3rd party apps?

Tags: django, heroku, django-1.8

I have a problem with migrations on heroku. 
I have just upgraded version of django from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 in my project on heroku, because of some missing migrations:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0005_alter_user_last_login_null.py#L14-L18

After this upgrade, on my local project I was forced to do standard procedure:
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate

Of course this new, generated migrations are outside of my git repository. If I will run heroku run this will generate new migrations in new dyno, so without any impact on my current slug.

What is the best solution for this situation? How to generate migrations or add missing migrations of django or 3rd part libs when e.g. you are doing upgrade of the libs? What is the best working strategy?

Comment: I know one method but I am not sure whether it's appropriate for your situation. Can you explain me why you need to `makemigrations` after django update? Is not that new migration already in django folder? Or you mean `makemigrations` for your apps?

Comment: This is very good question why there is no mogrations...

Comment: After migrate I have:
` Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.`

After makemigrations following migrations are created: 
`Migrations for 'account':
  0002_auto_20150521_2330.py:
    - Alter field email on emailaddress
`
So... migration files are missed after update... really strange for me.

Comment: Is not it related to `django-allauth`?. Post here that new migration if it's just one new.

Comment: @bellum you are right, this is 3rd party app django-allauth: 
python manage.py sqlmigrate account 0002
`BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE "account_emailaddress" ALTER COLUMN "email" TYPE varchar(254);
COMMIT;`
Should I run sql in my database? Or what is other best solution?

Answer (score 12):

Answer is quiet trivial, could be useful for others. 
To use MIGRATION_MODULES is the correct answer.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES